# What is the base collection class in scala?

Tags: scala

In java  we have java.util.Collection Interface is the base for all Collection classes.

Similarly What is the Base Class or Interface for all Scala Collections?

Comment: Traversable?  http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview

Comment: What are "all Collection classes"? Is Map collection class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All collections in **scala** extend trait **Iterable**. The Iterable also extends a trait **Traversable**. So, basically, **Iterable** is extended by following 3 types of collections in scala:

1). **Sequences** ( collection of elements stored either in linear or indexed form) for eg: Array, ArrayBuffer, List, ListBuffer, Vector etc

2). **Map** (stores data in key-> value form) eg: HashMap, ListMap etc

3) **Set** (stores unique elements only) eg: HashSet, BitSet etc